# Setting up infinispan server database

Tags: database, caching, jboss, infinispan

I am trying to use Infinispan for caching and have it store to a database, but I cannot figure out how to setup the server piece nor create the database portion.

Answer (score 0):

Infinispan cache loaders is exactly the mechanism you are looking for.

Since we don't know anything about your intention nor your architecture and application structure, please, see: http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_jdbc_based_cache_loaders for common JDBC related cache loaders and http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_sample_configurations for some code snippets and look around a little bit.

If you'll meet some specific problems, I suggest you to join #infinispan IRC channel on freenode and ask developers for specific question as response time here can be longer.

HTH

Comment: ok So, I am familiar with the loaders.  I had decided to use the JDBC StringCacheLoader, but my issue is how do I setup the server so that when I use the cache in my code, the server piece actually works.  I am using Jboss.  I am also trying to figure out how to create the database that infinispan hooks into.  I just really need a good tutorial, because I am confused on how the config files work (as far as where they go and so forth.)